# Difference between Return and Break statements

Tags: java

How does a `return` statement differ from `break` statement?. 

If I have to exit an if condition, which one should I prefer, `return` or `break`?

Comment: What do you mean by exit an if condition? You normally only use break in switch statements, or in loops, and you use return when you want to return to the invoker of a method. Doesn't matter if you are using Android or not. The answer is still the same :)

Comment: I mean, if the condition is not satisfied, I don't want further executions.

Comment: You should in that case return.

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same, and that they respectively obey their specifications in the Java Language Specification. And there is *no* way in Java to 'exit from an `if` condition'.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`break` is used when you want to exit from the loop, while `return` is used to go back to the step where it was called or to stop further execution.

Answer (score 149):

`break` is used to exit (escape) the `for`-loop, `while`-loop, `switch`-statement that you are currently executing.

`return` will exit the entire method you are currently executing (and possibly return a value to the caller, optional).

So to answer your question (as others have noted in comments and answers) you cannot use either `break` nor `return` to escape an `if-else`-statement per se. They are used to escape other scopes.

---

Consider the following example. The value of `x` inside the `while`-loop will determine if the code below the loop will be executed or not:

```
void f()
{
   int x = -1;
   while(true)
   {
     if(x == 0)
        break;         // escape while() and jump to execute code after the the loop 
     else if(x == 1)
        return;        // will end the function f() immediately,
                       // no further code inside this method will be executed.

     do stuff and eventually set variable x to either 0 or 1
     ...
   }

   code that will be executed on break (but not with return).
   ....
}
```

Comment: Notes: `break` also ends `switch`. `continue` will go directly to the next loop of a `for` or `while`.

Comment: Well you can use a `break` with a label to escape an if statement. So it is possible to escape a `if` statement.

Answer (score 25):

No offence, but none of the other answers (so far) has it quite right.

`break` is used to immediately terminate a `for` loop, a `while` loop or a `switch` statement. You can not `break` from an `if` block.

`return` is used the terminate a method (and possibly return a value).

A `return` within any loop or block will of course also immediately terminate that loop/block.

Answer (score 19):

You won't be able to exit only from an `if` condition using either `return` or `break`.

`return` is used when you need to return from a method after its execution is finished when you don't want to execute the rest of the method code. So if you use `return`, then you will not only return from your `if` condition, but also from the whole method.

Consider the following method:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    int i = 10;

    if(i==10)
        return;

    System.out.println("This will never be printed");
}
```

Here, using `return` causes to stop the execution of the whole method after line 3 and execution goes back to its caller.

`break` is used to break out from a `loop` or a `switch` statement. Consider this example -

```
int i;

for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            break;        // This break will cause the loop (innermost) to stop just after one iteration;
    }

    if(j==0)
        break;    // and then this break will cause the outermost loop to stop.
}

switch(i)
{
    case 0: break;    // This break will cause execution to skip executing the second case statement

    case 1: System.out.println("This will also never be printed");
}
```

This type of `break` statement is known as `unlabeled break` statement. There is another form of break, which is called `labeled break`. Consider this example -

```
int[][] arrayOfInts = { { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
                            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
                            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
                          };
int searchfor = 12;

int i;
int j = 0;
boolean foundIt = false;

search:
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor)
            {
                foundIt = true;
                break search;
            }
        }
    }
```

This example uses nested for loops to search for a value in a two-dimensional array. When the value is found, a labeled break terminates the outer for loop (labeled "search").

You can learn more abour `break` and `return` statements from [`JavaDoc`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Comment: He is able to return, but he will return out of the whole method.

Answer (score 8):

`Break` statement will break the whole loop and execute the code after loop  and `Return` will not execute the code after that `return` statement and execute the loop with next increment.

**Break**

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    print(i)
    if(i==2)
    {
      break;
    }
}
```

output: 0 1

**return**

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   print(i)
   if(i==2)
   {
    return;
   }
}
```

output: 0 1 3 4

Comment: Incorrect.  `return` also breaks the loop.  It would produce the identical output as the previous code which used `break`.
Also, note that the output produced by your code would be `0 1 2`, not `0 1`  because your print statement occurs before the equality check.

Comment: To produce `0 1 3 4`, you would need to use `continue` instead and place the print statement after the if statement.

Answer (score 6):

break:- These transfer statement bypass the correct flow of execution to outside 
of the current loop by skipping on the remaining iteration

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(i==5)
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
} 

output will be 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Continue :-These transfer Statement will bypass the flow of execution to starting point of the loop inorder to continue with next iteration by skipping all the remaining instructions .

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(i==5)
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
} 

output will be:
0
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
```

return :-
At any time in a method the return statement can be
used to cause execution to branch back to the caller of the method. 
Thus, the return statement immediately terminates the method in which
it is executed. The following example illustrates this point. Here,
return causes execution to return to the Java run-time system,
since it is the run-time system that calls main( ).

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(i==5)
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(i)
    }
} 


output will be :
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Great example to clarify difference between return|break|continue. A big thank! 
Only 1 things, the `System.out.println(i);` should be inside the for loop, btw :)

Answer (score 4):

You use **break** to break out of a loop or a switch statement.

You use **return** in a function to return a value. Return statement ends the function and returns control to where the function was called.

Answer (score 3):

`break` breaks the current loop and continues, while `return` it will break the current method and continues from where you called that method

Answer (score 3):

Break will only stop the loop while return inside a loop will stop the loop and return from the function.

Answer (score 2):

Return will exit from the method, as others have already pointed out. If you need to skip just over some part of the method, you can use break, even without a loop:

```
label: if (some condition) {
    // some stuff...
    if (some other condition) break label;
    // more stuff...
```

}

Note, that this is usually not good style, though useful sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

**How does a return statement differ from break statement?.**
Return statement exits current method execution and returns value to calling method.
Break is used to exit from any loop.

**If I have to exit an if condition, which one should I prefer, return or break?**

To exit from method execution use return.
to exit from any loop you can use either break or return based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

break just breaks the loop & return gets control back to the caller method.

Answer (score 0):

Break: Break statement will break the nearest loop or conditional statement and transfers the control to the statement that follows the terminated statement.

Return: Return statement will break the execution of the method in which it appears and return function result and control to the caller if any.

If function doesn't compute any value return can be used without any expression.

Find the code sn

Return Code :::

```
public class ReturnStatement {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var names = new String[]{"Jonas", "Sara", "Michael", "June", "Jamie"};

    for (String name: names) {
        if (name.startsWith("M")) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    System.out.println("Main method ends here");
}
```

}

[image: Return Statement]

Break Code :::

```
public class BreakStatement {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var names = new String[]{"Jonas", "Sara", "Michael", "June", "Jamie"};

    for (String name: names) {
        if (name.startsWith("M")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    System.out.println("Main method ends here");
}
```

}

[image: Break Statement Code]

Answer (score -1):

In this code i is iterated till 3 then the loop ends;

```
int function (void)
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
      if (i == 3)
      {
         break;
      }
    }
}
```

In this code i is iterated till 3 but with an output;

```
int function (void)
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
      if (i == 3)
      {
         return i;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to exit from a simple `if else` statement but still stays within a particular context (not by returning to the calling context), you can just set the block condition to false:

```
if(condition){
//do stuff
   if(something happens)
        condition = false;
}
```

This will guarantee that there is no further execution, the way I think you want it..You can only use break in a `loop` or `switch case`

Comment: `condition = false` accomplishes exactly nothing here. The `further execution` consists of executing whatever comes after this code, with or without it.