# break loop from handler

Tags: java, android, loops, handler

I need to break my loop from a handler in that loop, but there is a problem :

```
break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch
```

This is my Code :

```
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Break)
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
```

I can't use label break also, like this link : [Difference between Return and Break statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620949/difference-between-return-and-break-statements)

Comment: If your handler is only for the loop, why you just remove callbacks to your handler?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?  The `Runnable` doesn't make any sense with the break.

Comment: I am using handler for change UI of Android Program in a handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 10 Runnables to be run by the thread the Handler is associated with, then trying to stop the addition after the fact inside the Runnable.

If you want to stop the remaining runnables running at some point then, if as in your code the Runnable is the same then you can add the same runnable 10 times and remove the remaining using [removeCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

If the Runnables are different, you can either check your flag at the beginning of each run() method and `return` early, so the runnables are run but don't do much, or you can cause each Runnable to add the next one to run if the flag is not set.

Answer (score 2):

`break` can only let you stop a loop (for/while) or a switch.

If you want to stop a method from running further on, you should call `return`.

Comment: i want to break for loop but return don't break my loop

Answer (score 1):

No way. run() executes asynchronously, and may start after the loop executes all 10 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a boolean to achive your task.

```
                 boolean isBreak = false;
                 Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if(!isbreak)
                        {

                           mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                           if (Break)
                          isBreak = true;
                        }
                      });

                       }
                      }
```

Comment: Thre is a problem, isBreak need to be final then you can't change it in your handler.

Comment: Yes it has to be if we are using it inside anonymous local method inner class.