# how can I code a Javascript for loop so that it breaks when the first condition is met?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to write a script to find the greatest common factor (highest common factor/HCF), however the loop was counting downward, so I want to break as soon as it finds the first common factor (since it's counting downwards so this is also the HCF).

However, my code turned out to print all the common factors and did not break out of the loop as soon as it found 4, for HCF of 12 and 8.

Here it is:

```
function maxi(a, b) {
  for (var i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (var j = b; j >= 1; j--) {
      if (a % i == 0) {
        if (b % j == 0 && i == j) {
          console.log(i);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
maxi(12, 8);
```

Comment: Works fine with return/return i instead of break

Comment: Can you not just return i; instead of breaking the loop?

Answer (score 5):

i'm guessing you have the logic right.

just change

```
 if (b % j == 0 && i == j){
                    console.log(i);
                    break;
            }
```

to

```
   if (b % j == 0 && i == j){
                        console.log(i);
                        return;
                }
```

Comment: that was brilliant, thank you very much, it really helped.

would you please tell me what difference did return make and why is break not useful?

thanks in advance

Comment: @MohamedHegazy You have three nested for loops. You break out of the inner-most loop, but then the outer loop jumps back into the inner loop at the next iteration.

Comment: break will break out inner loop , and thus outer loop will still run . return will make your code to return to the function invocation site.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620949/difference-between-return-and-break-statements

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this is using "return" instead of "break".

```js
function maxi(a,b){
    for (var i=a; i>=1; i--){
        for (var j=b; j>=1; j--){
            if (a % i == 0){
                if (b % j == 0 && i == j){
                    return i;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

console.log(maxi(12,8));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why would return make the function run properly but break wouldn't?

Comment: The difference is that "break" statement only interrupts the inner-most for-loop, leaving the outer for-loop running. Whereas "return" exits the function altogether, returning the answer to the caller.

Answer (score 4):

Label your loops like thus:

```
function maxi(a,b) { 
loop1:
    for (var i = a; i >= 1; i--){
loop2:
        for (var j = b; j >= 1; j--){
            if (a % i == 0){
                if (b % j == 0 && i == j){
                    console.log(i);
                    break loop2; // Breaks out of all loops.
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

maxi(12,8);
```

People forget these exist, but they are a completely valid part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to test whether the desired output has been reached and put in a second break point in your outer for loop like this.

```
function maxi(a,b){
    var iAmFinished = false;
    for (var i=a; i>=1; i--){
        for (var j=b; j>=1; j--){
            if (a % i == 0){
                if (b % j == 0 && i == j){
                    console.log(i);
                    iAmFinished = true;
                    break;
            }
            }
        }
        if (iAmFinished) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
maxi(12,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you break, unless you specify otherwise, you break from the *nearest* loop.

You can use a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) to specify a specific loop to break from.

```js
function maxi(a, b) {
  outer:
  for (var i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
    inner:
    for (var j = b; j >= 1; j--) {
      if (a % i == 0) {
        if (b % j == 0 && i == j) {
          console.log(i);
          break outer;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
maxi(12, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two equally elegant ways to achieve the same effect.

#### Option 1 :

Use [**`return`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) instead of [**`break`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) :

```
function maxi(a, b) {
  for (var i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (var j = b; j >= 1; j--) {
      if (a % i == 0) {
        if (b % j == 0 && i == j) {
          console.log(i);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
maxi(12, 8);
```

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this
>   function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the
>   function caller. If the expression is omitted, undefined is returned
>   instead.
>
> [**source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

---

#### Option 2 :

Use [**`break`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) in combination with a [**`label`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) :

```
function maxi(a, b) {
  outerloop:
  for (var i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (var j = b; j >= 1; j--) {
      if (a % i == 0) {
        if (b % j == 0 && i == j) {
          console.log(i););
          break outerloop;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
maxi(12, 8);
```

> The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements.
>   It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.
>
> [...]
>
> You can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or
>   continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the
>   loop or continue its execution.
>
> [**source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)