# For loop with string.split to array, break after condition is met

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am trying to break the for loop and execute function only once after one of the string texts (conditions) are met.

I have tried with break, tried lots of other methods, but I couldn't get it to work with if conditions in for loop etc.

```java
static void show(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Arri<Mylist> notification) {

            ....

        String strings = "text1,text2,text3,text4,...";
        String[] stringarray = strings.split(",");

        for(String name : stringarray){
            notifyMe(name, notification);
        }

    private static void notifyMe(String text, @NonNull Arri<Mylist> notification) {
        if (notification.loadr().project().toString().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            Log.d("TAG", "contains:" + text);
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "doesnt contain:" + text);
        }
    }
```

At the moment it executes ofcourse more times but I need it only one time to execute function. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: not clear. what are you trying to do?

Comment: notifyMe(name, notification); function needs to be called only once if condition is met in for loop. else nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem, if anyone will need it here it is. If there are any better methods feel free to post.

```java
static void show(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Arri<Mylist> notification) {

            ....

        String strings = "text1,text2,text3,text4,...";
        String[] stringarray = strings.split(",");

        for(String name : stringarray){
          if (notifyMe(name, notification)) {
               break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean notifyMe(String text, @NonNull Arri<Mylist> notification) {
        if (notification.loadr().project().toString().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `notifyMe` inside an `if`:

```
for (String name : stringArray) {
    if (someLogic(name)) {
        notifyMe(name, notification);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: for the OP: make sure the `someLogic(name)` returns a boolean `true` or `false` value.

Comment: I have updated my question with function, I have also tried this with break

Answer (score 0):

Just use `break` statement if you want to break loop when your condition is met:

```
public void breakIt(){
    String stringToSplit = "text1,text2,text3";
    String[] strings = stringToSplit.split(",");
    String condition = "text2";

    for (String s : strings){
        if (s.equals(condition)) {
            System.out.println(s);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

You can use also `return` to "leave" the loop. See more info about differences between `return` and `break`:
[break vs return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620949/difference-between-return-and-break-statements)

Comment: it is better to have a generic conditional statement like code posted by @Mureinik.

Comment: I'll remember for the next time! It can still be here as another example

Comment: I have tried this, updated with function, since other function check if contains the array strings

Answer (score 0):

Get your condition and remove from notifyMe and put into for loop or use a boolean response at this one and evaluate into for loop. Otherwise you cannot stop this loop.

Comment: the thing is i cannot use boolean method on void

Comment: notifyMe cannot return a boolean if value contains lower case word? If you explain better what you want with this code we can help you.