# Using Break Statement vs Early Return in Exiting for-of Loop Block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, break, for-of-loop

I have a `for of` loop where I need to exit if there are no resulting values. It occurs to me that I could use an early `return` statement to handle this, or use a `break` statement. To be clear, in this case, there is no additional code to execute WITHIN this block of code after the part I'm skipping, so I'm assuming either one would work here (break or return). Any functional or performance reason to use one over the other in this particular case?

OPTION 1: (break)

```
  for (let diff of differences) {
    if (!diff.path) break;

    if (diff.path[0] !== "updatedAt") {
      const docChange = new ChangedProp(doc, diff, lastEditedBy, "customer");
      docChange.log();
    }
  }
```

OPTION 2: (return)

```
  for (let diff of differences) {
    if (!diff.path) return;

    if (diff.path[0] !== "updatedAt") {
      const docChange = new ChangedProp(doc, diff, lastEditedBy, "customer");
      docChange.log();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suspect it makes no difference at all in performance, but I would think in terms of how you imagine the function might change over time; one might be better than the other when considered that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Return and Break statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620949/difference-between-return-and-break-statements) - while in Java context, the answer applies to Javascript as well.

Comment: That's a fair point, in which case `break` would probably be the better choice.

Comment: @nbokmans, this is a JavaScript question, not Java.

Comment: @Ademo that is irrelevant. Just because it is tagged Java doesn't mean it doesn't apply to Javascript (in this situation).

Comment: I think that's misleading. If one searched specifically for a JS answer, they would likely not find that answer. Nor could they assume it would apply in both cases.

Comment: The question is about programming semantics, not language implementation. Just because it's a function() in javascript and a void() in java doesn't mean they're not both methods, no? Also it is quite literally the first result for googling "difference between break and return".

Comment: I think `return` conveys the intention of terminating the function, whereas `break` leaves the programmer wondering what might happen after the loop. I would use `break` if you need to cleanup after the loop, and `return` if I immediately want to return the result of the function, but that's highly subjective. - It probably compiles to the same assembler code.

Comment: But implementations can differ between programming languages, so, personally, I would never assume that what's true for one language is for another. For instance, I wouldn't assume how Python handles loops would necessarily be equivalent to JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any functional or performance reason to use one over the other in this particular case?

No, if we assume that the `for-of` loop is the last thing in the function containing it. There may be style arguments one way or the other, but no functional or performance reason.

Obviously, if there's code **after** the `for-of` loop, using `break` will result in that code getting run, and using `return` will result in that code being skipped. That's a significant functional difference:

```js
function a(array) {
  for (const value of array) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log("This line gets reached");
}
function b(array) {
  for (const value of array) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log("This line does NOT get reached");
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
a(arr);
b(arr);
```

In that example, the code in `a` and `b` are the same other than that `a` uses `break` and `b` uses `return` (and the text logged at the end is slightly different).

Without that `console.log` after the loop, though, no functional difference.

Comment: Agreed. And therefore, in terms of being explicit, I think "break" is the better option here, because, even if there isn't additional code to run now, there may be in the future.

Comment: @Ademo - Yeah, it's totally a judgement call and often a case-by-case one depending on what the function does. :-)