# Difference between 'break' and 'return'

Tags: java

In the code below, when I use 'break' instead of 'return' it also prints the second println(). Why is this so?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n : ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();

    for(int count = 2; count <= num/2; count++) {
        
        if(num%count == 0) {
            System.out.println(num + "is not a prime number.");
            **return**;
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(num + "is a prime number.");

}
```

Comment: If the `return` is replaced with `break`, it `break`s the `for` loop that it is in. `return` exits the function`main()` wherever it is called (bypassing the second print). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620949/difference-between-return-and-break-statements has the answer in greater detail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Return and Break statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620949/difference-between-return-and-break-statements)

Comment: ``break`` "breaks" out of a loop by jumping to the next line after the loop. ``return`` "returns" from a method by ending the method and returning to right after the method call started from.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example to explain the difference:

```
void explainBreak() {
  int i = 10;
  while (i > 0) {
    if (i < 5) {
      break;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    i -= 1;
  }

   while (i > 0) {
     System.out.println(i);
     i -= 1;
   }
}
```

Its output is:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Lets replace break with return:

```
void explainBreak() {
  int i = 10;
  while (i > 0) {
    if (i < 5) {
      return;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    i -= 1;
  }

   while (i > 0) {
     System.out.println(i);
     i -= 1;
   }
}
```

This will return:

```
10
9
8
```

### EDIT

Briefly:

`break`: breaks from the current loop (if any)

`return`: returns back to the parent-caller who called the function

Answer (score 0):

`break` is only terminating the For Loop not the whole execution. (Second println will execute).
the `return` will complete the execution and handover to the caller where the main method was called and no further execution beyond that point in the method (no execution of second println).

Answer (score 0):

`break` will just stop the for loop from executing further but the code after the loop will continue as normal. Since the second print is outside the loop that line will be executed.

Whereas a `return` statement will spit you out of the main method and nothing after that executes.

A general rule of thumb "If you encounter a return statement, then nothing beyond that in the function will execute, other than finally blocks associated with a try block containing the return".

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, and I think you will know the difference with the help of your code only. see this is your code:

```
 import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n : ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();

    for(int count = 2; count <= num/2; count++) {
        
        if(num%count == 0) {
            System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number.");
            return;
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(num + "is a prime number.");
     }

}
```

When you write the return keyword it will terminate the function that has the return keyword, here your main function is the only function you have so after the first System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number."); line it will exit the main function and no further code will be executed. but the trick here is that it will only happen if it is not a prime number because you have written it inside the if the condition. So for a prime number let say 5 it will check the if condition if(num%count == 0) and it will be false so it will print after the for loop end : System.out.println(num + "is a prime number.");

[Return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07rko.png)

Now take the case when we have break here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter n : ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();

    for(int count = 2; count <= num/2; count++) {
        
        if(num%count == 0) {
            System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number.");
            break;
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(num + " is a prime number.");
     }

}
```

It will check the if condition print the line System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number."); and the break from "loop" meaning that it will come out of the loop, in this case only the for loop is terminated. so the next instruction after for loop will work fine.
[Break Statement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnVmz.png)

Answer (score -1):

Break is used when you want to exit from the loop, while return is used to go back to the step where it was called or to stop further execution.